# regular expression for string comparssion using php

Tags: php

I am new to regex in php, I am trying to get the values between `@` and `.` in a string.
for example if a string contains value `abc@gmail.com` i want to get only `gmail` as output.

So far i have tried using `explode` but no result can any one please suggest or guide me how to do this using regular expression. thanks in advance.

Below is the sample what i did so far.

```
<?PHP
    $str = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $piece = explode('.', $str);
    $piece1 = explode('@', $str);
    echo $piece[1]; 
    echo $piece1[1];
?>
```

Comment: "Below is the sample what i did so far." -- and it should work. Why do you want to use something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str = 'abc@gmail.com';

preg_match('/@([^.]+)/', $str, $match);

echo $match[1]; // gmail
```

Breakdown of above:

- `@` start search from the character `@`
- `[^.]+` match 1 or more characters that are not the character `.`
- The `( )` is to capture that portion in a backreference which in this case would be the index 1
- So we access it through `$match[1]`

Comment: in reefer to the above sample, can anyone please help how to get the value from "@" till "." example if string contains value "abc@gmail.com", so output should be "@gmail." using regular Expression.

Comment: @Patel use the same code but use `$match[0]` instead of `$match[1]` if you want the period as well still use `$match[0]` but change regex to `'/@([^.]+)\./'`

Answer (score 1):

Simple as mentions above :

```
$input=hardiksondagar@gmail.com;
// now you want to fetch gmail from input user PHP's inbuilt function 
preg_match('/@([^.]+)/', $input, $output);
echo $output[1]; // it'll print "gmail"
```

- Documentation of function : [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: in reefer to the above sample, can anyone please help how to get the value from "@" till "." example if string contains value "abc@gmail.com", so output should be "@gmail." using regular Expression.

Comment: just change this line :
    `preg_match('/@([^.]+)/', $input, $output);` 
to   `preg_match('/(@(.*\.))/', $str, $match);`

Comment: Removed your unrelated link again. As I noted elsewhere, don't do this anymore. You can post your website link in your profile.