# String match in php using regex

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regular expression for string comparssion using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036117/regular-expression-for-string-comparssion-using-php)

can anyone please help how to get the value from "@" till ".", Example if string contains value "abc@gmail.com", so output should be "@gmail." using regular Expression.

Below is the sample code which out puts only "gmail".

```
$str = 'abc@gmail.com';
preg_match('/@([^.]+)/', $str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Come on, seriously, you just posted a tiny variation on this an hour ago.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not work because

1. Your capturing group excludes the `@` symbol
2. You forgot to escape your `.` character (outside the character set), because `.` is a metacharacter in regex (meaning matching all characters).

Your regex should be

```
preg_match('/(@[^.]+\.)/', $str, $match);
```